# What contributions from Glavieux & Thitimajshima were "merged" into Claude Berrou's now-famous 1993 talk "Near Shannon limit error-correcting coding"?

Tags: information-theory

At `01:15:13` in the delightful video [The Bit Player | Claude Shannon | Father of Information Theory | IEEE Information Theory Society](https://youtu.be/JP1Ljp8X6hg?t=4513) [Andrea Goldsmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Goldsmith_(engineer)) recounts attending a session of the IEEE International Conference on Communication conference and hearing a presentation by [Claude Berrou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Berrou) which listed [Alain Glavieux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Glavieux) and [Punya Thitimajshima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punya_Thitimajshima) as coauthors.

From Wikipedia's [Turbo code; History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_code#History):

> The first public paper on turbo codes was "Near Shannon Limit Error-correcting Coding and Decoding: Turbo-codes".[2] This paper was published 1993 in the Proceedings of IEEE International Communications Conference. **The 1993 paper was formed from three separate submissions that were combined due to space constraints.** The merger caused the paper to list three authors: Berrou, Glavieux, and Thitimajshima (from Télécom Bretagne, former ENST Bretagne, France). However, it is clear from the original patent filing that Berrou is the sole inventor of turbo codes and that the other authors of the paper contributed material other than the core concepts.<sup>[improper synthesis]</sup>
>
> [2] C. Berrou, A. Glavieux and P. Thitimajshima, "[Near Shannon limit error-correcting coding and decoding: Turbo-codes. 1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/397441)" Proceedings of ICC '93 - IEEE International Conference on Communications, 1993, pp. 1064-1070 vol.2, doi: 10.1109/ICC.1993.397441.

Since [Turbo codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_code) using forward error correction are in such widespread use today, and there is much intellectual property involved, there was *a lot* of attention paid to the IP aspects of who invented what.

But I'd like to ask more about the talk itself and what the material from Glavieux and Thitimajshima was that was merged.

**Question:** What were the contributions from Glavieux & Thitimajshima that were "merged" into Claude Berrou's now-famous 1993 talk "Near Shannon limit error-correcting coding and decoding: Turbo-codes. 1"?

Summaries are helpful but if the actual separate submissions or subsequently published works by these two are available, that would be even more informative.